# Justification of given matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> What is an example of a 3 x 2 matrix **A** and a 3 x 1 matrix **y**, such that the equation **Ax = y** has no solution and yet **A** is also related to any 2 x 1 matrices u and v, such that if **Au = Av**, then **u = v**. Explain why this example is workable.

I do not know what's the concept behind this.

Comment: Remember that $Ax=y$ always has a solution (*for appropriately sized $A$ and $y$*) when $A$ is surjective which happens precisely when the rank of $A$ is equal to the number of rows.  Further remember that $Ax=Ay\implies x=y$ when $A$ is injective which happens precisely when the rank of $A$ is equal to the number of columns.  So... find an example of a $3\times 2$ matrix whose rank is equal to the number of columns but not equal to the number of rows.  Then find your $y$ such that $y$ is not in the columnspace of $A$.

Comment: Additional hint: if the third row of $A$ is entirely zero, then $Ax$ will have zero for a third entry.